# MVC4 Passing Model to Controller - Some of Model Null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having problems sending a model from a form on my view to my controller. The main class I has the data in it but the sub classes have lost their values.

I have a main Quotation class like this:

```
public class Quotation
{
    public string QuotationID { get; set; }
    public TaxiPartner taxiPartner { get; set; }
    public TaxiCompany taxiCompany { get; set; }
    public int maxNumberOfSeats { get; set; }
    public int maxNumberOfBags { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
}
```

Then for example I have the TaxiPartner class:

```
public class TaxiPartner
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public bool supportsPasswordReset { get; set; }
    public bool supportsValidatebysms { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the form in my view

```
@if (Model.listOfQuotations.Count > 0)
{
<h3>You can book online with:</h3>
foreach (var item in Model.listOfQuotations)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("BookingPage1", "SearchResults", FormMethod.Post))
    {    

<div class="well">
    <div>
        <h4>@item.taxiCompany.Name</h4>
    </div>
    <div style="float: right;">
        <h2>@string.Format("{0:C}", item.price)</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>Product Type:</b>
        <img style="width: 15px;" src="~/Content/images/icon-@item.taxiPartner.cabforceProductType-orange-40px.png" />
        (1 = Best Value, 2 = Executive, 3 = Minibus)
    </div>
    <div><b>Services:</b> @item.taxiCompany.services (0 = Outdoor pickup, 1 = Meet & greet pickup)</div>
    <div><b>Maximum Number of Seats:</b> @item.maxNumberOfSeats <b>Maximum Number of Bags:</b> @item.maxNumberOfBags</div>
    <div>@Html.ActionLink("Book Now", "BookingPage1", item, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })</div>
</div>
    }
}
```

}

I then have the following action in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BookingPage1(Quotation chosenQuote)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

When my controller action is called I can see the values for QuotationID, maxNumberOfSeats, maxNumberOfBags, and price but the values that were contained in taxiPartner and taxiCompany are all NULL?

I have debugged and the value of "item" in the view does contain the values I need but they have disappeared once it gets to the controller.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: you seem to be having nested view models,to render them properly and get them posted u need to use EditorFor()

Comment: Please add your form code... may be you don't have all the fields in your form and that is why you don't see them posted.

Comment: ive added more code. hopefully it helps? I still cant work it out @CodeIgnoto romias

Answer (score 1):

Only the model fields assigned to input types will available in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Merely displaying the values isn't enough for it to be passed back. If you have a value that you don't have an input for, you should use a hidden value:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.TaxiPartner.Name)
```

Also, something you may want to think about: if you have a bunch of properties that aren't being used/displayed in this view, you may want to think about creating a separate view model that only holds the values you need for that view rather than putting a bunch of hidden input fields to pass around values that aren't ever needed.